Redirecting Issue in Next.js – Infinite Redirect Loop or Unexpected Behavior
I am Using clerk Authentication for signIn / SignUp .
this is my redirecting page code :
import { onAuthenticatorUser } from '@/actions/user'
import { redirect } from 'next/dist/server/api-utils';
import React from 'react'

type Props = {}

const AuthCallBackPage = async(props: Props) => {

  const auth = await onAuthenticatorUser();
  if(auth.status === 200|| auth.status === 201){
    return redirect(`/dashboard/${auth.user?.firstname}${auth.user?.lastname}`)

  }
  if(auth.status === 400 || auth.status === 500 || auth.status === 404){
    // return{ redirect:{destination:`/auth/sign-in`}}
    return redirect(`/auth/sign-in`)

  }

}
// module.exports = Dashboardpage
export default AuthCallBackPage

redirect throwing an error like this :
Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)

index.d.ts(28, 56): An argument for 'statusOrUrl' was not provided.

(alias) redirect(res: NextApiResponse, statusOrUrl: string | number, url?: string): NextApiResponse<any>import redirect

@param res — response object

@param statusOrUrl — HTTP status code of redirect

@param url — URL of redirect

After Logging or signUp My url is not going to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/userfirstname/userlastname .
I also tried to redirect with this code
     return{ redirect:{destination:`/auth/sign-in`}}

But still not working .
I am Expecting that when i login or signUp my code should redirect to :
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/userfirstname/userlastname .
